# Visual Studio 2010 + Windows 10 not allowing me to clean solution

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, csproj

We have a working project. Recently some of us got new machines, and we loaded Windows 10 on them. We currently use Visual Studio 2010.
Before, on Windows 7, I could clean and build my solution with no problems.
Now however, I can't. I am always getting a warning:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4181,5): warning MSB3061: Unable to delete file "C:_repo****_desktop\bin\Debug****.exe". Access to the path 'C:_repo****_desktop\bin\Debug****.exe' is denied.
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4181,5): warning MSB3061: Unable to delete file "C:_repo****_desktop\bin\Debug****.pdb". Access to the path 'C:_repo****_desktop\bin\Debug****.pdb' is denied.

Now we have many solutions. One has four (4) projects, and those build and clean successfully. I have ensured that I, as the administrator, make the folder security options full for everyone. There is no read-only folder. 
To work around this, I have to close my solution, delete the Debug folder, and open the solution again. This is time consuming and very annoying.
I run VS in Administrator Mode, I make sure there is nothing else using anything, yet I can't get this error to go away. 
I have also researched, to no avail, as most answers are make sure the folder is not read-only, close the .exe, etc.

If someone could please inform me as to what the problem really is. Is it Windows 10? Visual Studio? I am also running VS SP 1 if that helps. I have tried creating a new solution and copying all work over, yet I get the same error.

If you need anything, please let me know and I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Did you change your AV solution? Sounds like something is locking these files open - perhaps for a scan. A tool like Process Explorer from sysinternals can tell you which processes are holding handles open

Comment: @ChrisBecke seems to only be devnev.exe and ****.vshost.exe that are using my files, which would be Visual Studio. So unless that's the problem?

Comment: @ChrisBecke funny thing now, I killed the Enable VS hosting process and it has cleaned and built my solution several times now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like all I had to do was to change the Debuggers options on my projects properties.
The

> Enable the Visual Studio hosting process

box was ticked before. Ever since I un-ticked it, my project has been running well. It cleans, builds, everything good now.
[image]